# Tridion DynamicContent.Query Searching By Component Template

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I'm trying to render all component presentations from the broker database with a certain component template. Here's the query code so far:

```cs
using Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent;
using Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query;

ItemTemplateCriteria CTCriteria = new ItemTemplateCriteria(1111);
PublicationCriteria pubCriteria = new PublicationCriteria(10);
AndCriteria finalCriteria = new AndCriteria(pubCriteria, CTCriteria);

Response.Write("<h1>START</h1>");

Query q = new Query();
q.Criteria = finalCriteria;

string[] result = q.ExecuteQuery();

if (result != null && result.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (string r in result)
    {
        Response.Write("<h1>" + r + "</h1>");
    }
}
else {
    Response.Write("Result is null or 0-length.");
}
Response.Write("<h1>END</h1>");
```

I keep getting `null` results. I do have dynamic content publishing setup in `cd_storage_conf.xml` and a few component presentations published in the Broker database.

My understanding from [this document](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_708AA488429D4457AC303DD121B22183#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DBroker&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1354014111542&currentQuery=Broker&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocpub_concept_37EFA836EC214C71BF8EA0B8F6603162&addHistory=true&filename=PublicationCriteria.xml&docid=pub_concept_37EFA836EC214C71BF8EA0B8F6603162&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=) is that, I should be able to retrieve *related* component URIs using this approach.

**My Questions**:

1. Is my understanding of the capabilities of the `Query` class correct?
2. Did I miss anything, config and code-wise?
3. Is there any other way of retrieving broker content by component template?

**EDIT**:

Additional info: Regarding `ItemTemplateCriteria`, I only assumed that this is used for searching records by Component Template. I assumed because there is another criteria class called `PageTemplateCriteria`. Please correct me if this assumption is invalid.

**EDIT**:

Additional info: I've inspected the `COMPONENTS`, `SCHEMA` and `TEMPLATES` tables in the broker database but didn't find the published components there. By default rule in the `cd_storage_conf.xml`, published content must go to the broker. For reference, here's my config:

```xml
<Publication Id="57" defaultStorageId="brokerdb" cached="false">
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" storageId="brokerdb" cached="false" />
    <Item typeMapping="BinaryMeta" cached="true" storageId="brokerdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="BinaryVariant" cached="true" storageId="brokerdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="defaultFile" cached="true"/> 
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentMeta" cached="true" storageId="brokerdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentationMeta" cached="true" storageId="brokerdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ItemMeta" cached="true" storageId="brokerdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="LinkInfo" cached="true" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>
    <Item typeMapping="DynamicLinkInfo" cached="true" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="true" storageId="defaultFile"/> 
    <Item typeMapping="PageMeta" cached="true" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Reference" storageId="brokerdb"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Schema" storageId="brokerdb"/>
</Publication>
```

Comment: Guys, this turns out to be a configuration issue. My deployer's `cd_storage_conf.xml` was using file system for everything **except** component presentations. After configuring and republishing the components, I was able to retrieve the components!

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Comment: Sure Bart! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double check your `cd_storage_conf.xml` and database to check the items are stored there. If your data is going to the file system it will not be query-able.

Specifically I think the `ComponentPresentationMeta` must be going to the DB for this scenario to work.

Also check your `cd_licenses.xml` file, if it is expired, if it is (even if the `cd_storage_conf.xml` is correct), the items will end up on the file system.

Comment: I did, Chris. The `cd_storage_conf.xml` for the deployer was wrong. The config in my question came from the website's config. This is why the component info was not published to the broker db. After I synchronized both configuration, I was able to publish to the database and retrieve using the DynamicContent.Query API.